# Need another relative word for "Female"

Tags: meaning

Word "Fella" will indicate the gender "Male". Can anyone say the word like "fella" for the gender "female"?.

Comment: OP is flooding the site with sexist questions which show no research effort. However the question can be improved by adding more context leading up to the word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fellow, the original word, has three main meanings:

> 1. A male person in general - *I saw a fellow waiting by the car.*
> 2. One of a pair - *I found one shoe but could not find its fellow.*
> 3. A member of a group of people who have shared interests or activities, especially formal membership - *She was a Fellow of the Royal Institute of British Architects.*  In this instance it is gender neutral.

You would normally only use *fella* as a short form of Number 1. I assume you are looking for a female equivalent of this usage.

Some male terms have obvious female 'opposites':

> Guy - gal
>  Lad - lass
>  Boy - girl
>  Son - daughter
>  Husband
>   - wife

However there are many words for males and females which do not match up, and this is usually because of the different roles men and women have held thoughout history and in different cultures. For instance, *maid*, or *maiden*, is an old-fashioned word meaning an unmarried woman who is assumed to be a virgin (because sex for women outside of marriage has been forbidden). There is no equivalent male word.

*Fellow* is from Old Norse and is to do with [cattle trading](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fellow). It's therefore a male-dominated word with no female equivalent. You must therefore choose one of the many words which apply to women, and the appropriateness of your choice would depend on context.

Answer (score 1):

The closest equivalent is [*gal*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gal), as in [*Guys and gals*](https://www.google.com/search?q=guys%20and%20gals).

Be careful how you use it however, it *can* be perceived as patronizing.

Other options are:

- *[lass](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lass)* (chiefly British I believe), meaning young girl. Again, can be badly received if addressing a grown woman you don't know.
- [*gel*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gel--3), again chiefly British and I doubt anyone under 50 or so would use it.
- [*fem*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fem), not very common.

Comment: Male's opposite gender will be Female like wise what is the word for "Fella"?

Comment: @KalyanaKumarA sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fella This link will show you informal term for "Male" as like as I want informal term for "Female".

Comment: Fellas, it may be time to refer the O.P. to [ell.SE]. This question should NOT be reposted over there. However, that might be a better place to ask future questions.

Comment: @J.R. fair enough.

Comment: @Kalyana: For most Anglophones, "fella/fellow" is hopelessly dated slang. I've no idea if there was anything that could meaningfully be called a "female equivalent" back when it was commonly used, but you have to bear in mind that "publically-acknowledged" gender distinctions in language were very different in earlier societies.

Comment: I think _ladies_ could work, too. Granted, _ladies_ is usually considered a counterpart to gentlemen, but it's not too hard to imagine a teacher trying to get a class to quiet down, beginning with: "Fellas, ladies, please, quiet down."

Comment: @J.R. I think you're dating yourself, lack of grey hair notwithstanding :)

Comment: I would think that ‘lass’ was even more typically Irish than British, no? And ‘fem’ is quite common, but certainly not as a female equivalent of ‘fella’—more as an after-all-male equivalent of ‘effeminate or flamboyant fella’!

Comment: I'd use _ladies_ before I used _lasses_, _gels_ or _fems_. I might opt for _gals_ ahead of _ladies_, though.

Comment: @J.R., I find it much easier to imagine a teacher nowadays beginning with, “All right, now shut it, you little twerps!” ;-þ

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Northern Ireland counts as Britain and anyway, it is very common in Scotland and quite common in the north of England in general. And how about _shut it you little twerps and twerpettes?_ ;) As for _fem_ it is actually quite often used as a neutral term for women in science fiction literature.